# Запись JSON в файл с помощью GSON

Tags: java, json, файлы, gson, filewriter

Мне нужно записать новый объект в **users** с помощью GSON

**data.json**

```
{
  users: [
    {
      "name": "Alex",
      "age": 20
    },
    {
      "name": "Dima",
      "age": 12
    },
    {
      "name": "Masha",
      "age": 18
    }
  ]
}
```

**Запись**

```
try(FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(path,true)) {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();

    User user = new User();
    user.setName("Carl");
    user.setAge(14);

    writer.write(gson.toJson(user));
    writer.flush();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    System.out.println(ex);
}
```

**Получается при такой записи следующее:**

```
{
  users: [
    {
      "name": "Alex",
      "age": 20
    },
    {
      "name": "Dima",
      "age": 12
    },
    {
      "name": "Masha",
      "age": 18
    }
  ]
}{
  "name": "Carl",
  "age": 14
}
```

**Нужно, чтобы запись была такой:**

```
{
  users: [
    {
      "name": "Alex",
      "age": 20
    },
    {
      "name": "Dima",
      "age": 12
    },
    {
      "name": "Masha",
      "age": 18
    },
    {
      "name": "Carl",
      "age": 14
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы добавить новый объект в массив users в data.json с помощью GSON, Вам необходимо сначала прочитать существующий файл data.json, десериализовать его в объект класса Data, добавить новый объект в массив users, а затем сериализовать и записать обратно в файл data.json. Пример кода может выглядеть так:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
try (FileReader reader = new FileReader(path)) {
    Data data = gson.fromJson(reader, Data.class);
    User user = new User();
    user.setName("Carl");
    user.setAge(14);
    data.users.add(user);
    try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(path)) {
        gson.toJson(data, writer);
    }
} catch (IOException ex) {
    System.out.println(ex);
}
```

PS: Вы должны создать класс Data и User для сериализации и десериализации. В классе Data должен быть массив List users.

Comment: Спасибо. Вы мне очень сильно помогли)